# Dojo DTL: Cannot read property 'for' of undefined

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to render a template with dojo DTL, but it's giving an error on parsing the template string. For some reason DTL doesn't "like" iteration "for".

```
var template = new dtl.Template("<div>{% for item in items %}<option value=''>{{ item }}</option>{% endfor %}</div>");
```

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'for' of undefined 
Sample code can be found here: http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/f8997/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to include  "dojox/dtl/tag/logic" to require.

Comment: Had this same problem. Thanks for following-up!